# python list / numpy array indexing using tuple unpacking possible?

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering if tuple unpacking can be used in a *"index from ... to"* kind of style, so with `inds = (a,b)`, `M[*inds]` would lead to `M[a:b]`.

I often have tuples which contain the indices that I use to slice my data into some interesting subset, and would think that something like the proposed above would be convenient. Is there a way to do this?

thanks for input

Comment: You can try to patch/overload the __getitem__ method of your list objects, such thath `M[inds]` is supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking, but you have to unpack them into a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), and then use the slice for indexing:

```
>>> A = list(range(10))
>>> inds = 3, 6
>>> A[slice(*inds)]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Also works with `numpy`:

```
>>> B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> ind_x, ind_y = (0,2), (1,None)
>>> B[slice(*ind_x),slice(*ind_y)]
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6]])
```

Remember that `A[start:stop:step]` is just syntactic sugar for `A[slice(start,stop,step)]`.

Comment: thank you for reminding me. Still new to this stackoverflow system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `tuples` (at least not in the start-stop-step way). But you can always use [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).

some examples:

```
indx = slice(start, stop, step)
indy = slice(starty, stopy, stepy)
sliced = M[indx]
sliced2 = M[:,indy]
sliced3 = M[(indx, indy)]
```